# list inside a class does not update in database

Tags: java, db4o

i have a problem with db4o that i'm unable to fix.
i have 2 classes.

```
public class Profile {
    private String Name;
    private List<Action> Actions;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public List<Action> getActions() {
        if (Actions == null)
            Actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        return Actions;
    }
}
```

and the other class.

```
public class Action {
   private String _Name;

   public Action(String Name) {
    _Name = Name;
   }

   public String getName() {
    return _Name;
   }
}
```

the thing is when i store in db4o for the first time the Profile and the list of actions save fine aswell. when i update (adding or removing items from the list of actions) it wont reflect in the database (db4o).

what i do to save the data is just to db4o.store(Profile). i dont know if maybe i must to store the list something like db4o.store(Profile.Actions).

any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your update depth isn't set properly. To update the inner list of your `Profile` class, you need to set up your configuration with a higher update depth. See [this article](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/basics/update_concept.htm) and [this article](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/usage_pitfalls/update_depth.htm) in the db4o references.

For a `List`, I recommend an update depth of 2 or higher.

```
EmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
configuration.common().objectClass(Profile.class).updateDepth(2);
```

An update depth of 2 will update all the way down to the `Action` object, including the `Action` itself (I believe) so that if you change an `Action` that's already in the list, it will update too. Just be careful, as setting the update depth too high can cause performance issues.

Comment: i dont know why i have tried this before and doesnt worked... but now i tried again and worked like a charm...

Comment: @Rothariger Just be happy the bits flipped the right way the second time :)